# Is it possible to add css style to print_r function in codeigniter php?

Tags: php, html, css, arrays, codeigniter

I have to display my username from a database and it's done using the `print_r` method. Now I would like to add some CSS functions to make the output large and bold.

Is it possible to add such a style to `print_r`?

```
<?php print_r($this->session->userdata['userName']); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, use this

```
$data['username'] = $this->session->userdata['userName'];
```

And in you template file, use this

```
<div class="your-class"><?php echo $username?></div>
```

Its preety simple. I suggest you to spend sometime about mvc work flow.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do in this way...

```
<?php

$styleArray = array('apple','banana','carrot');
echo '<pre><h1>';
print_r($styleArray);
echo '</pre></h2>';

?>
```

You can also add whatever class u wish.

Answer (score 0):

u can use function in php like this

```
<?php 
   pre($this->session->userdata['userName']);
   function pre($str = null){
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($str);
      echo "</pre>";
   }
?>
```